# Object required UFT/VBS

Tags: vbscript

Hi i am new to uft and vbs what i am trying to do is take the innertext from a webelement and get the account number from it i split the string into an array and knowing what words will come up in the text i want to select the random generated account number. My problem is that i get an erro0r on "Application" in the if statement where is says:

Object required: 'Application'
Line (60): "If Arry(i).ToString <> ("Application" or "Number") Then".

i have no clue how to proceed with this so any help would be appricated.

```
App_Num = oPage_Account.WebElement("Application 
Number").GetROProperty("innertext")
sDelimiter = " "
Arry = Split(App_Num, sDelimiter) 'Split the string by the spaces
iLoop = UBound(Arry) 'Find the size of the array
For i = 0 to iLoop ' loop to see if accepted
   If Arry(i).ToString <> ("Application" or "Number") Then
   App_Num = Arry(i)
   Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "Account Num", "Account Number is Assigned" 
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write the If condition as:

```
If strComp(Arry(i),"Application")<>0 or strComp(Arry(i),"Number")<>0 then
    ' your code...
    '...
    '...
End If
```

OR simply remove the `toString()`(shown below) because Arry(i) is not an object and hence you are getting the Object Required error.

```
 If Arry(i)<>"Application" or Arry(i)<>"Number" then
    ' your code...
    '...
    '...
End If
```

I would recommend the first method though.

More info on [StrComp](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_strcomp.asp)

Answer (score -2):

please change this line

```
If Arry(i).ToString <> ("Application" or "Number") then
```

to

```
If (Arry(i).ToString <> "Application") Or (Arry(i).ToString <> "Number") then
```

Comment: how you declared arry array please check it, it can be issue.

Comment: check this arry(i).ToString also it may be giving error.